# History of Spring Framework

Tags: spring

I apologize for posting here, since it does not seem to be the perfect place, but I don't know which other StackExchange site would be better.

My question would be that is there any source about how and why Spring Framework was created? I'm more interested in story based text rather than technical details. I could not find too much by Googling. I'd use it in a school project for introduction.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The history is nicely explained on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“*The question is, what aspect of control are [they] inverting?” Martin Fowler posed this question about Inversion of Control (IoC) on his site in 2004. Fowler suggested renaming the principle to make it more self-explanatory and came up with Dependency Injection*.

For insight into IoC and DI, refer to Fowler's article at http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html.

Useful links:

1. http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread/23358.html
2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch01.html

I hope this can answer *why*.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be useful! :)